# How to correctly return error to user on error - Azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am creating an Azure function that should return an error to the user when an exception is thrown. The issue I am having is that I can either throw the exception, or return something to the user, but not both.

With this code an exception is thrown, but nothing is returned to the user:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    try {
        null.toString()
    } catch (e) {
        response(context, 500, "message")
        throw e
    }
}

function response(context, statusCode, message) {
    context.res = {
        body: message,
        status: statusCode
    };
}
```

If I add in a `context.done()` then I can return a message to the user, but the exception no longer shows up:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    try {
        null.toString()
    } catch (e) {
        response(context, 500, "message")
        throw e
    }
}

function response(context, statusCode, message) {
    context.res = {
        body: message,
        status: statusCode
    };
    context.done()
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: No, I am using Webstorm